# Security header failed in Angular 10 application

Tags: angular, security, header

Getting low grade(F) while scanning angular application in https://securityheaders.com/ even though added required header options in all api calls via interceptor shown below

```
intercept<T>(req: HttpRequest<T>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
  req = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
      'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
      'Referrer-Policy': 'strict-origin'
    },
  });

Can anyone help on this?
```

Comment: Those headers need to be set on the server (response) headers, not in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that site is strictly checking your REST API calls, it's looking for headers on the initial content serve from your domain. e.g. if you go to Google in your browser, what the response headers are on the GET request to https://www.google.com